# Configuring Active Directory Domain Services in a network that has Univention DNS Servers

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns

I've been tasked with the creation of an ADDS forest (single domain, for now) and after reading best practices, i decided to name the domain **ad.mycompanydomain.com**.

Two Univention Corporate Server installations are currently present in the network, and they are the primary domain servers for the network, while hosting all records for mycompanydomain.com, even internet facing ones.

I was wondering if it was possible to have my Domain Controllers be the primary DNS servers in the network, while keeping current records and non-ad records in the UCS servers.

What would be the correct installation scenario in this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kudos to you for choosing "ad.mycompanydomain.com" for the AD forest root domain name. You're making the Right Choice(tm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "...have my Domain Controllers be the primary DNS servers for the network..." I *think* you're saying "Configure domain-joined computers to use the Domain Controllers as their DNS servers."

Assuming that's correct I would configure the DNS servers on the Domain Controllers with conditional forwarders for the zones the Univention Corporate Servers are authoritative for. This will cause the Windows DNS Server to query the Univention Corporate Servers on behalf of clients.

If the Univention Corporate Servers can resolve Internet names recursively you could just configure a non-conditional forwarded and let them resolve all Internet names for clients too.